# Checking if item in a list?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a piece of code that is checking if a user is in a table of data.  I can get it to produce a list of the user details but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it won't let me produce a greeting if the user name is valid.

The code is:

```
import sqlite3
import itertools
conn = sqlite3.connect("student_test_db.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()
## connects to the database

username = input("please enter your username")
username = (username,)
c.execute( 'SELECT fname,sname,username  FROM students WHERE username =?', username )

user_check = c.fetchall()
print (user_check)
print (type(user_check))

if username in user_check:
  print ("Welcome")
else:
  print ("Wrong username")
```

What I get out of this is:

```
please enter your usernameBobF
[('Bob', 'Fleming', 'BobF')]
<class 'list'>
Wrong username
```

I cannot see why as the username is clearly matching what is in the list.  I am a novice user so apologies if it i something really obvious!

Comment: `'Bob' in [('Bob', 'Fleming', 'BobF')]` will always return `False` because it is tuple inside list, use index as `0` like `user_check[0]`

Comment: Try ``username in user_check[0]``

Comment: Actually `username in user_check[0]` also will not work because `username` is also a tuple

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, but `user_check[0]` is a tuple (`('Bob', 'Fleming', 'BobF')`) and `username` is also a tuple `(BobF',)`

Comment: And you don't need to import `itertools` for this situation.

Comment: @EveDanvers, you can also check with if `user_check` is empty or not. If empty you can prompt "Wrong username". But solution pointed by Ignacio is better

Answer (score 2):

Since your username is likely to be unique, change your `c.fetchall()` to `c.fetchone()` which should give you the required row instead of a list of rows with only one row in it. Check the sqlite3 documentation related to the [fetch methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone).

As pointed out in a comment, you shouldremove the line reassigning the `username` variable `username = (username,)` and directly use `(username,)` in `c.execute()`.

Answer (score 1):

Beside change `fetchall()` to `fetchone()`, the problem is that you assign tuple `(username,)` to variable `username`, it changed from `Bob` to `(Bob,)`, when your code check variable `username` is in the result, it will use the tuple `(Bob,)` instead of `Bob`. That's why the code always print `Wrong username`. you have to change to a new variable name not `username`, Change your code to:

```
import sqlite3
import itertools
conn = sqlite3.connect("student_test_db.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()
## connects to the database

username = input("please enter your username")
username_sql = (username,)
print username
c.execute( 'SELECT fname,sname,username  FROM students WHERE username =?',username_sql)

user_check = c.fetchone()
print (user_check)
print (type(user_check))

if username in user_check:
    print ("Welcome")
else:
    print ("Wrong username")
conn.close()
```

output:

```
please enter your username'Bob'
Bob
(u'BobF', u'Fleming', u'Bob')
<type 'tuple'>
Welcome
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved it!
When I changed the username variable for use in the query I added a "," after it.  That was why it was not finding the user in the list. I added a separate variable for the username in the query and all works.
Thanks for all the advice.